# tikzplotlib to save multiple images in python

Tags: python

I need to use the tikzplotlib library to save images that are generated from my python code, but I can't seem to find a way to save the images that are being created within a for loop.

I searched online but couldn't seem to find a solution that uses this library. 
Can someone help me please?

Thanks :)

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution: 
a = str(i) + '.tex'
tikz_save(a)

Comment: If you post that as an answer then someone else with the same problem might be able to find it more easily :)

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis thanks for reminding me, just posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found a solution:

```
for i in range(5):
    # define the graph/image you want to save
    a = str(i) + '.tex'
    tikz_save(a)
```

This will save all the images you need in your loop :)